# Задача о принадлежности точки к отрезкам

Tags: java, алгоритм

Есть задача:

В первой строке задано два целых числа 1≤n≤50000 и 1≤m≤50000 — количество отрезков и точек на прямой, соответственно. Следующие n строк содержат по два целых числа ai и bi (ai ≤ bi) — координаты концов отрезков. Последняя строка содержит m целых чисел — координаты точек. Все координаты не превышают 10^8 по модулю. Точка считается принадлежащей отрезку, если она находится внутри него или на границе. Для каждой точки в порядке появления во вводе выведите, скольким отрезкам она принадлежит.

Я придумал решение: Сортируем отрезки по началу. Далее бежим по точкам и по отрезкам. Смотрим, если точка принадлежит отрезку, то увеличиваем счетчик, и отмечаем, что она принадлежит хотя бы одному отрезку. Далее смотрим, если случилось так, что точка не принадлежит какому-то отрезку, но хотя бы одному принадлежит, то всем последующим она тоже не принадлежит. (т.к. отрезки по возрастанию начальных координат). Но у меня проблема с одним тестом:

```
[6 6]
[2 3]
[2 5]
[3 5]
[2 7]
[5 7]
[3 7]
```

- отрезки,
  1 2 3 5 6 7 - точки.
  Выдает 0 3 5 5 1 1, когда ответ 0 3 5 5 3 3. Хочу узнать, где ошибка в моем алгоритме. И если она есть, то натолкнуть меня на верное решение :)

  import java.io.BufferedReader;
      import java.io.IOException;
      import java.io.InputStreamReader;
      import java.util.*;

  ```
  import static java.lang.Integer.parseInt;

  /**
   * Created by Andrey on 31.12.2018.
   */
  public class Stepic {
      static int scanInt() throws IOException {
          return parseInt(scanString());
      }



      static String scanString() throws IOException {
          while (tok == null || !tok.hasMoreTokens()) {
              tok = new StringTokenizer(in.readLine());
          }
          return tok.nextToken();
      }

      static BufferedReader in;
      static StringTokenizer tok;
      public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
          in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
          int n = scanInt();
          int m = scanInt();
          int[] ans = new int[m];
          List<Segment> segments = new ArrayList<>();
          for(int i = 0 ; i < n; i++){
              segments.add(new Segment(scanInt(),scanInt()));
          }

          segments.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(o -> o.x));

          int[] dots = new int[m];
          boolean[] dotsB = new boolean[m];
          for(int i = 0; i < m; i++){
              dots[i] = scanInt();
          }

          for(int i = 0; i < dots.length; i++){
              for (Segment segment : segments) {
                  if (segment.x <= dots[i] && segment.y >= dots[i]) {
                      ans[i]++;
                      dotsB[i] = true;
                  } else {
                      if (dotsB[i]) {
                          break;
                      }
                  }
              }
          }

          for(Segment segment : segments){
              System.out.println(segment.x + " " + segment.y);
          }


          for (int an : ans) {
              System.out.print(an + " ");
          }

      }

      public static class Segment{
          public int x;
          public int y;


          public Segment(int x, int y) {
              this.x = x;
              this.y = y;
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: В принципе нет необходимости сортировать отрезки.

Comment: И что за белиберда у вас с "правильным ответом"? Правильный ответ `0 3 5 5 4 3`, а не `0 3 5 5 3 3`. Точка 6 принадлежит 4 отрезкам, а не 3.

Comment: Неверная проверка принадлежности. В геометрии есть формулы, используемые для проверки принадлежности точки отрезку. Не надо изобретать к ним свои. Плюс, нет смысла в сортировке.

Comment: @Anton M: Что же там неверного??? 1. Задача не имеет никакого отношения к проверке принадлежности точки отрезку в геометрии. Под "отрезком" в данном случае понимается одномерный интервал.  Никаких "формул" тут не нужно - проверка принадлежности тривиальна (и в коде сделана правильно). 2. Без сортировки или иных упорядочивающих структур данных задачу эффективно решить невозможно (т.е. невозможно решить в рамках поставленных временных ограничений).

Comment: @AnT согласен. Не вник в вопрос. Тогда надо еще отрезки объединять, с целью уменьшения времени выполнения

Comment: @AntonM Интервалы изначально задуманы как перекрывающиеся и в вывод надо выдать именно количество перекрывающихся интервалов. В такой ситуации объединять можно лишь касающиеся интервалы. Не думаю, что такая овчинка стоит выделки: время поиска касаний и объединения вряд ли окупится.

Comment: @AnT эх. Дочего же лень в разборе задания доводит... Согласен. Был не прав. Извиняюсь

Comment: @AnT, зачем выдавать перекрывающиеся интервалы, если мне даны конкретные точки? Нужно просто каким-то образом ускорить алгоритм, я придумал как, но не могу найти логическую ошибку..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Далее смотрим, если случилось так, что точка не принадлежит какому-то отрезку, но хотя бы одному принадлежит, то всем последующим она тоже не принадлежит. (т.к. отрезки по возрастанию начальных координат).

Это неверно. Допустим у нас есть отрезки `[0 100] [10 20] [40 80]`. Они отсортированы по началам. Точка `50` принадлежит первому отрезку, не не принадлежит второму. Из этого вы делаете странный вывод, что "всем последующим она тоже не принадлежит". Но это не верно. Она принадлежит `[40 80]`.

Ваш подход, даже будучи реализованным правильно, будет очень неэффективным, ибо выполняет поиск в полном массиве отрезков для каждой точки. То, что отсортированность массива отрезков дает вам возможность завершить поиск раньше на основе проверки условия `segment.x > dots[i]`, помогает, но погоды не делает. В среднем вам придется проверять половину всех отрезков для каждой точки.

---

Вы пытаетесь реализовать on-line алгоритм, т.е. алгоритм, который обрабатывает каждую точку независимо от остальных точек. Не нужно этого делать, когда вам в условии ясно сказано, что задача является off-line, т.е. *все тестовые точки заранее известны*. Off-line решение всегда будет эффективнее on-line решения (или, по очевидным причинам, не хуже его).

Если бы стояла задача построить on-line решение, то эффективным подходом было бы построение такой классической структуры данных, как [дерево отрезков](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree). Вашей сортировкой отрезков вы фактически делаете шаг в этом направлении. Но, еще раз, в рамках вашей постановки задачи нет смысла тратить на это усилия.

Эффективное off-line решение данной задачи может основываться на классическом принципе слияния двух отсортированных массивов. Оба массива - и отрезков, и точек - надо отсортировать заранее, а затем синхронным проходом по обоим массивам получить ответ задачи. Структура алгоритма напоминает также алгоритм сканирующей прямой в одномерном варианте (поддерживает множество  "активных" отрезков).

Например, на С++

```
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  unsigned n, m;
  std::cin >> n >> m;

  using Segment = std::pair<int, int>;
  std::vector<Segment> segments(n);
  for (Segment &segment : segments)
    std::cin >> segment.first >> segment.second;

  std::vector<int> points(m);
  std::vector<unsigned> counts(m);
  for (int &point : points)
    std::cin >> point;

  // Сортируем отрезки по началам
  std::sort(segments.begin(), segments.end());

  // Сортируем точки (через индексный массив)
  std::vector<unsigned> point_index(m);
  std::iota(point_index.begin(), point_index.end(), 0u);
  std::sort(point_index.begin(), point_index.end(), 
    [&](unsigned li, unsigned ri) { return points[li] < points[ri]; });

  // Заводим список активных отрезков - упорядочен по концам отрезков
  auto cmp_second = 
    [](const Segment *lhs, const Segment *rhs) { return lhs->second < rhs->second; };
  std::multiset<const Segment *, decltype(cmp_second)> active_segments(cmp_second);
  // Изначально этот список пуст

  auto it_segment = segments.begin();
  for (unsigned i_point : point_index)
  {
    // Очередная точка
    int point = points[i_point];

    // Поддерживаем список активных отрезков
    // Удаляем уходящие отрезки ...
    while (!active_segments.empty() && (*active_segments.begin())->second < point)
      active_segments.erase(active_segments.begin());

    // ... и добавляем приходящие отрезки
    for (; it_segment != segments.end() && it_segment->first <= point; ++it_segment)
      if (it_segment->second >= point)
        active_segments.insert(&*it_segment);

    // Ответ для текущей точки - количество активных отрезков
    counts[i_point] = active_segments.size();
  }

  for (unsigned count : counts)
    std::cout << count << " ";

  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f37d52223571f42d

Правильный ответ на вашем входе, кстати, `0 3 5 5 4 3`, а не `0 3 5 5 3 3`.

Comment: Спасибо! Очень помогли!

Answer (score 1):

Уберите все, что связано с `dotsB[i]`. Логика

```
} else {
  if (dotsB[i]) { 
    break; 
  }
}
```

неправильная.

Comment: А можете объяснить, почему?

Comment: Если бежать по всему массиву точек, и всему массиву отрезков, то будет Time Limit.

Comment: @Dr.kott9ra Выведите отрезки после сортировки - и увидите.

Comment: @Dr. kott9ra: Если бежать по *всему* массиву отрезков для *каждой* точки, то будет time limit. Но ваш подход будет бежать по *половине* массива отрезков (в среднем) для *каждой* точки. Это ничего принципиально не меняет. Будет все тот же time limit.